# Strange behaviour of rotation transform for CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, quartz-graphics

I'm using CALayer for interactive book engine and want to rotate CALayer around it center but when I apply rotation transform (using angle which is based on user input) to CALayer it goes crazy: layer stretches and moves in very strange way and disappears. What I do is

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions];
...
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1);
...
[CATransaction commit];
```

Interestingly, when my angle is M_PI or M_PI/2, or it's scale transform everything is ok, but when its rotation and any other angles layer goes crazy.

Does anybody know what's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the origin of a CALayer at the center? If not, you'll need to first transform the origin to the center, do the rotation, then transform it back.

Comment: try this `layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);`

Comment: Is your layer owned by a view? If so, is the view using auto-layout? The auto-layout system will try to set the frame of the view, and that typically leads to strange results if your view is transformed.

Comment: Yes my orign is at the center, I tried to force using suggested `layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);` but nothing changed.
This is not view's layer - I created it with [CALayer layer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the reason myself: it was because in parallel I moved layer using `.frame` instead of `.position` property: frame property itself is calculated based on transform thus setting it produced that 'crazy' behavior.